# Fire-and-forget with async vs "old async delegate"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, c#-5.0

I am trying to replace my old fire-and-forget calls with a new syntax, hoping for more simplicity and it seems to be eluding me. Here's an example

```
class Program
{
    static void DoIt(string entry) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + entry);
    }

    static async void DoIt2(string entry)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        Console.WriteLine("Message2: " + entry);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // old way
        Action<string> async = DoIt;
        async.BeginInvoke("Test", ar => { async.EndInvoke(ar); ar.AsyncWaitHandle.Close(); }, null);
        Console.WriteLine("old-way main thread invoker finished");
        // new way
        DoIt2("Test2");   
        Console.WriteLine("new-way main thread invoker finished");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Both approaches do the same thing, however what I seem to have gained (no need to `EndInvoke` and close handle, which is imho still a bit debatable) I am losing in the new way by having to await a `Task.Yield()`, which actually poses a new problem of having to rewrite all existing async F&F methods just to add that one-liner. Are there some invisible gains in terms of performance/cleanup?

How would I go about applying async if I can't modify the background method? Seems to me that there is no direct way, I would have to create a wrapper async method that would await Task.Run()?

Edit: I now see I might be missing a real questions. The question is: Given a synchronous method A(), how can I call it asynchronously using `async`/`await` in a fire-and-forget manner without getting a solution that is more complicated than the "old way"

Comment: async/await is not really designed for offloading synchronous workloads onto another thread. I've used async/await in some pretty huge projects with not a `Thread.Yield` in sight. I see this code as an abuse of the the async await philosophy. If there's no async IO, async/await is probably the wrong solution.

Comment: I would disagree, especially in my case; there is no sound reason to force http requestor to wait for a complete process to finish to receive a response available at the very begining. The rest can be safely offloaded. The only question really is can async/await help, make worse or is just unusable in this scenario. I must admit I had different ideas about what it was.

Comment: I don't disagree that the work might need offloading. I'm saying that using `async/await` combined with `Task.Yield` has a bad smell. Using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` would be a better fit here. After all, that's really what you're trying to do... send the work to the ThreadPool with a resonably minimal code footprint, right?

Comment: oh, ok. fair comment, I misunderstood your claim. I guess I just thought that with async I'll just call a method and it will magically start on another thread :). Speaking of different approaches, does anyone know of a comparison between the three? `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` vs `Task.Factory.StartNew` vs `delegate.BeginInvoke`? If I am going to make changes, I might as well do it in the best available way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fire and forget async method in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502745/fire-and-forget-async-method-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Avoid `async void`. It has tricky semantics around error handling; I know some people call it "fire and forget" but I usually use the phrase "fire and crash".

> The question is: Given a synchronous method A(), how can I call it asynchronously using async/await in a fire-and-forget manner without getting a solution that is more complicated than the "old way"

You don't need `async` / `await`. Just call it like this:

```
Task.Run(A);
```

Comment: what if A() has async method calls in it?

Comment: I mean, how do you avoid the warnings about not awaiting a task?

Comment: That warning is there because fire-and-forget in an `async` method is almost certainly a mistake. If you're *positively* sure that's what you want to do, you can assign the result to an unused local variable like this: `var _ = Task.Run(A);`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, and, yes, fire and forget is what I want, its a socket accept loop, async void seems perfect. Given that the method always properly handles exceptions (http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/07/08/c-sharp-async-tips-and-tricks-part-2-async-void.aspx) would you agree or am I just going to get in a pickle?

Comment: @AnthonyJohnston: I meant *calling* a fire-and-forget method from an `async` method is almost certainly a mistake. In your case, since you always handle exceptions within the method, there's little difference between `async Task` and `async void`. I would still lean a bit more towards `async Task`, just because `async void` to me implies "event handler".

Comment: But what if you want to run the method A() on the UI-Thread and not on a thread pool? And you cannot afford to await A() because it will run for a longer time (not blocking) asynchronously on the UI-Thread. For example a click handler which has to fire and forget call A() and do some stuff afterwards. But otherwise doesnt care about A(). A() just has to be started.

Comment: @Blechdose: I don't see why you can't `await` it. But if you want to fire-and-forget - and **are willing to accept the limitations** - specifically that *you cannot know when the task completed* and *you cannot know whether there was an error* - then you can just do `var _ = A();`

Answer (score 79):

As noted in the other answers, and by this excellent [blog post](https://jaylee.org/archive/2012/07/08/c-sharp-async-tips-and-tricks-part-2-async-void.html) you want to avoid using `async void` outside of UI event handlers. If you want a *safe* "fire and forget" `async` method, consider using this pattern (credit to @ReedCopsey; this method is one he gave to me in a chat conversation):

1. Create an extension method for `Task`. It runs the passed `Task` and catches/logs any exceptions:

   ```
   static async void FireAndForget(this Task task)
   {
      try
      {
           await task;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          // log errors
      }
   }
   ```
2. Always use `Task` style `async` methods when creating them, never `async void`.
3. Invoke those methods this way:

   ```
   MyTaskAsyncMethod().FireAndForget();
   ```

You don't need to `await` it (nor will it generate the `await` warning). It will also handle any errors *correctly*, and as this is the only place you ever put `async void`, you don't have to remember to put `try/catch` blocks everywhere.

This also gives you the option of *not* using the `async` method as a "fire and forget" method if you actually want to `await` it normally.

Comment: Well, if I have a Task, I'll just Run it, no?

Comment: @mmix That depends, you could use a `Task` object and run it, but thats not using await/async. This is how you do "fire and forget" with await/async. Note that this is much *more* useful when you are invoking Async framework methods, and you want to use them in a "fire and forget" sort of way.

Comment: Hi, its an old post, but generally the idea was to use language "flow" elements to achieve fire and forget, without implicitly using Task object as such. WE came to a conclusion that its not possible since calling async does not raise new thread until it awaits. If I have Task object then I just Run()-it and it will fire and forget.

Comment: @mmix No problem, this just came up in a discussion I had with Reed Copsey, and in a separate question we had a discussion about using `async void` to do fire-and-forget where I was pointed to this question as to why not to do that. I was adding this as the "correct" way to utilize `async void` to do that.

Comment: I don't understand the fascination with the async/await keywords – the point of await is to simplify the fire-but-DON'T-forget scenarios?

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll This is true, but if the API you are using already uses `Task` objects then this methodology proves very useful.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll: True "fire and forget" is extremely rare. It's completely different than "return void", which in the `async` world is equivalent to `async Task Method()`. The problem with using "fire and forget" is that it's *forgotten*. None of your other code will ever know if it completes. Errors may or may not be caught and logged - it depends on when the host process exits. Fire and forget in the synchronous world is just throwing a delegate on the thread pool that catches and ignores all exceptions. True fire and forget should almost *never* be used.

Comment: Is this answer still the best way to do fire & forget in `ASP.NET Core 2.1`?

Comment: @Wellspring probably? I suppose that depends on what you are doing since fire and forget in the web world is a weird concept, which is what most Core apps are doing

Comment: Mostly just looking for a solution to send email notifications in the background of certain Actions, which the website user doesn't need to be delayed for.

Comment: @Wellspring due to how ASP.NET manages the lifetime of objects post-request, there's whole libraries to manage that (like Hangfire). I wouldn't recommend just sending a task out in that kind of scenario

Answer (score 24):

To me it seems that "awaiting" something and "fire and forget" are two orthogonal concepts. You either start a method asynchronously and don't care for the result, or you want to resume executing on the original context after the operation has finished (and possibly use a return value), which is exactly what await does. If you just want to execute a method on a ThreadPool thread (so that your UI doesn't get blocked), go for

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoIt2("Test2"))
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: the more I experiment with it the more it seems so. async is just for processes where you have meaningful continuation on the results from asynchronous task. No continuation need, no support (other than Task.Yield()). I guess I got sniped by marketing again...

Comment: When on subject, any real differences between `delegate.BeginInvoke` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: @mmix, the biggest difference with using Task is that if an exception occurs in the Task, it will wind up being thrown in the finalizer of the Task object, since there is nothing observing the faulted state of the Task.  If you don't register for the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event, this can potentially cause a nasty crash without triggering your usual last-resort logging methods.  It also has the unfortunate side effect of not crashing until GC causes the finalizer to run, whereas an invoked delegate will crash the app immediately after the exception.

Comment: @DanBryant: [This has changed in .NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx). `UnobservedTaskException` will no longer crash the process; if you don't handle it, the exceptions are silently ignored.

Comment: @StephenCleary, interesting, I didn't realize that.  That's actually scarier.

Comment: I felt the same way at first; it took me a *long* time to come around to appreciating that design. `Task`-based code in the future will be `async`-based; in this new world, an unobserved `Task` *is* a fire-and-forget `Task`. This doesn't violate the fail-fast philosophy any more than the old behavior. The old behavior would crash by default because some error happened *some indeterminate time before*, so the old behavior wasn't "fail-fast" anyway.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I think you're right, actually.  It always bothered me that it would throw on the finalizer thread, but there wasn't really a better way of handling it.  It really doesn't change much, as best practice is still to handle the UnobservedTaskException event.  It just gives more flexibility now to decide how to handle the 'by the way, maybe you should've failed' event.

Answer (score 1):

My sense is that these 'fire and forget' methods were largely artifacts of needing a clean way to interleave UI and background code so that you can still write your logic as a series of sequential instructions.  Since async/await takes care of marshalling through the SynchronizationContext, this becomes less of an issue.  The inline code in a longer sequence effectively becomes your 'fire and forget' blocks that would previously have been launched from a routine in a background thread.  It's effectively an inversion of the pattern.

The main difference is that the blocks between awaits are more akin to Invoke than BeginInvoke.  If you need behavior more like BeginInvoke, you can call the next asynchronous method (returning a Task), then don't actually await the returned Task until after the code that you wanted to 'BeginInvoke'.

```
    public async void Method()
    {
        //Do UI stuff
        await SomeTaskAsync();
        //Do more UI stuff (as if called via Invoke from a thread)
        var nextTask = NextTaskAsync();
        //Do UI stuff while task is running (as if called via BeginInvoke from a thread)
        await nextTask;
    }
```

Comment: Actually we use F&F to avoid blocking the http caller and it has more to do with caller limitations than our own. The logic is sound because caller does not expect a response other than message received (the actual process response will be posted on another channel unrelated to this, or http for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class I put together based on Ben Adams' tweet about constructing such a construct. HTH  https://twitter.com/ben_a_adams/status/1045060828700037125

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace
namespace System.Threading.Tasks
{
    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "VariableHidesOuterVariable", Justification = "Pass params explicitly to async local function or it will allocate to pass them")]
        public static void Forget(this Task task, ILogger logger = null, [CallerMemberName] string callingMethodName = "")
        {
            if (task == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(task));

            // Allocate the async/await state machine only when needed for performance reasons.
            // More info about the state machine: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/11/30/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003978
            // Pass params explicitly to async local function or it will allocate to pass them
            static async Task ForgetAwaited(Task task, ILogger logger = null, string callingMethodName = "")
            {
                try
                {
                    await task;
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
                {
                    // log a message if we were given a logger to use
                    logger?.LogError(tce, $"Fire and forget task was canceled for calling method: {callingMethodName}");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // log a message if we were given a logger to use
                    logger?.LogError(e, $"Fire and forget task failed for calling method: {callingMethodName}");
                }
            }

            // note: this code is inspired by a tweet from Ben Adams: https://twitter.com/ben_a_adams/status/1045060828700037125
            // Only care about tasks that may fault (not completed) or are faulted,
            // so fast-path for SuccessfullyCompleted and Canceled tasks.
            if (!task.IsCanceled && (!task.IsCompleted || task.IsFaulted))
            {
                // use "_" (Discard operation) to remove the warning IDE0058: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the
                // current method continues before the call is completed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#a-standalone-discard
                _ = ForgetAwaited(task, logger, callingMethodName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```