# Exception is not bubbling up

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to catch a thrown Exception, but it doesn't bubble up to where it was called. It breaks in `InsertNewUser`'s catch block, saying

> "An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in PeakPOS.exe but was not handled in user code"

If I click on debugger Continue, it goes to some file called `App.g.i.cs` and breaks on a line I don't understand but has something to do with debugging on break. The application terminates after that.

Why is it saying the exception is unhandled when it is being rethrown and then re-caught and handled (to-be handled)?

---

**AccessViewModel.cs**

```
public void SaveNewUser(Popup popup)
{
    UserAccounts.Add(TempUser);

    string salt = PeakCrypto.GenerateSalt();
    string hash = PeakCrypto.GenerateHashedPassword(Password + salt);
    try
    {
        PeakDB.InsertNewUser(TempUser, salt, hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //TODO notify user that new account could not be saved
    }

    CreateNewAccount();

    if (popup != null)
        popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

**PeakDB.cs**

```
public static async void InsertNewUser(UserAccount user, String salt, String hash)
{
    var db = await DatabaseHelper.GetDatabaseAsync();

    try
    {
        using (var userStatement = await db.PrepareStatementAsync(
            "INSERT INTO AccessAccounts (FirstName, LastName, Salt, Hash) VALUES(@first, @last, @salt, @hash)"))
        {
            userStatement.BindTextParameterWithName("@first", user.FirstName);
            userStatement.BindTextParameterWithName("@last", user.LastName);
            userStatement.BindTextParameterWithName("@salt", salt);
            userStatement.BindTextParameterWithName("@hash", hash);
            await userStatement.StepAsync();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: log the exception error
        throw;
    }
}
```

**App.g.i.cs**

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
    UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    };
#endif
```

Comment: Did you try unchecking the checkbox saying `Break when this Exception occurs` and run again? I think while in debug mode it does break at exception

Comment: @Saagar: Yes. What happens is it goes to the App.g.i.cs file and breaks on the if statement just as before, it just doesn't break in catch anymore. I wonder if I'm misunderstanding try/catch. Is catching an exception not handling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behavior for `async` operation. Your code handles/catches exceptions thrown from synchronous part of the method, but lets application wide handle to deal with async part.

You can observe behavior you expect if you explicitly throw exception on first line of `InsertNewUser` method (synchronous part).

Fix: properly `await` your `async` method.

```
// must return at least `Task` to be awaitable
public static async Task InsertNewUser(...
```

And than `await` the method (note that "async is viral" - [Async/Await
Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)):

```
   try
   {
        await PeakDB.InsertNewUser(TempUser, salt, hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e) ...
```

Or at least `.Wait` if it console app (WPF/WinForm/Asp.Net will deadlock - [await vs Task.Wait - Deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock)):

```
   try
   {
        PeakDB.InsertNewUser(TempUser, salt, hash).Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception e) ...
```

If you can't do either - at least use proper [Fire-and-forget with async vs "old async delegate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803012/fire-and-forget-with-async-vs-old-async-delegate) to call `async void` methods.

Note: `async void` is bad practice and should only be used for form events.

Comment: Thanks, Alexei. It worked. Appreciate the links since I'm new to C# and have only briefly skimmed async/await feature and do not understand it very well.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers welcome. If you need to work with `async`/`await` I strongly suggest to scan through top answers by [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) before doing any serious work in that area.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem where my exceptions would hang, but it was because I was calling a web service from a web service using await.  My fix was to apply ...

```
.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)
```

... on my inner web service call.  Now when then inner web service generates an exception I receive the exception as expected.