# Is it wrong to use ManualResetEvent with async code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am looking for the best practices to synchronize Tasks (not even sure that this is semantically right, I should probably say synchronize Threads with async code).

Take the following code:

```
Task.Run(async () => await lib.WaitAsync());
Task.Run(async () => await lib.WaitAsync());
Task.Run(async () => await lib.WaitAsync());

// Synchronize all waiters
lib.Release();

// All Tasks shall be completed
```

When working with Threads, I used to do that with `ManualResetEvent`. So my first (simplified) approach would be:

```
Task WaitAsync()
{
   await Task.Run(() => manualResetEvent.WaitOne());
} 

void Release()
{
   manualResetEvent.Set();
}
```

Now I see that people have made their own implementation of async `ManualResetEvent`.

What is wrong with the original approach and why would someone prefer an async implementation ?
Is it because of the cancellation ? The exceptions unwrapping/handling ?

And more generally, is there any disadvantage when using the regular Thread synchronization objects (Mutex, Semaphore, ...) with async code ?

Thank you

Comment: `What is wrong with the original approach` - assuming the original code is the one that uses `manualResetEvent`, it's burning a thread on waiting when it [does not have to](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). The code prior to it, with several `Task.Run`s, is also not great because it's [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053175/11683). And it's probably worth mentioning that [async is not about threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17661428/11683).

Comment: With Async code you should almost never use `Task.Run()` to execute an async method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An asynchronous `Task` may use multiple threads when progressing from one internal asynchronous operation to the next, and may not utilize [any thread at all](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) for most of its lifetime. This is desired, because it promotes scalability. Blocking threads is a waste of resources. And all threading synchronization primitives (`Mutex`, `Semaphore`, `WaitHandle` etc) are doing just that, they block threads.

On the contrary no threads are blocked when throttling asynchronous operations with [`SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync), which is the only available built-in mechanism for blocking tasks asynchronously AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks GSerg as well. This is exactly the type of information I needed : when a Task is awaited, the current worker isn't blocked and continues other processing whereas a mutex/semaphore would block the thread. Now it make totally sense to avoid using primitive synchronization objects with async code.