# Strange behavior when process won’t start unless another totally unrelated process is started right after it

Tags: c#, .net, windows-task-scheduler

I ran into a peculiar situation with the following code sample that I don't understand. Below is a complete program that starts a process of `youtube-dl.exe` that downloads a youtube video. Both `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg` binaries are present in the same directory as `Task_Starter.exe` (my program).

```cs
const string destinationFolder = @"C:\Users\Home\source\repos\Task Starter\Task Starter\bin\Release";

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "youtube-dl.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4TOrB7at0Y";
process.StartInfo.Arguments += (" -o " + "\"" + destinationFolder + "/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" +
                                "\" --restrict-filenames --no-mtime --ffmpeg-location ffmpeg.exe");
Console.WriteLine("arguments: " + process.StartInfo.Arguments);
 
process.Start();
//Process.Start("notepad.exe");  // <--What is going on here?
 
Task.Run(() => {
    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
       string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
 });

Console.ReadLine();
```

The strange part about it is that this code does not start the process when being run inside `Rider` but does exactly what it should when launching `Task_Starter.exe` in `cmd`.

It also does not start the video download when I run it via a task scheduler manually pressing `Run` button in Task Scheduler.

`schtasks /Create /SC ONLOGON /TN "Youtube DL Starter" /RL HIGHEST /TR "'C:\Users\Home\source\repos\Task Starter\Task Starter\bin\Release\Task_Starter.exe'"`

But it does start correctly if I just add `Process.Start("notepad.exe");` anywhere below `process.Start();`

If I add that, then it successfully launches `youtube-dl.exe`, downloads the video both when executed within `Rider` and if executed via task.

I hope you can point out what I am missing here. **How launching a completely separated process of `notepad.exe` influenced what other parts of my code do?**

`Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363`
`.NETFramework v4.6.1`

Comment: What is the behavior if you synchronously do a StandardOutput.ReadToEnd instead of the Task?

Comment: Apparently the extra delay introduced by starting the notepad gives the previously started process enough time to start up and generate output so that you can read it straight away without blocking on `ReadLine()`. Otherwise you reach `Console.ReadLine()` too early and become locked up (because you have a [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053175/11683) on your task).

Comment: @CaiusJard If I move while loop outside the Task.Run() it does work correctly without the need for the strange notepad startup. This could be related to what GSerg said as well.