# Stuck with async await thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, xamarin.forms, async-await

In constructor I want to call one method type :

```
private async Task OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum
```

and I want to wait that method while its finish, and I have more method(3) like this and I want to call this 3 methods in background thread and don't wait him to finish, just want to wait first method. And I want to them executing parallel.
I have methods async Task,and in constructor of view model I call like this

```
OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, 
    DatumVrednost).Wait();
OnLoadPrometNedelja(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDatNedelja).Wait();
```

if I don't place .Wait() on the end, program doesn't work. I see in debug mode they run asynchronly, but time spent tell me that they sub(one method time + second method time + ....).
Can someone help me, this is for me very stuf...

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Comment: why does it have to be in the constructor? btw. You should post the constructor to give us the context where the code is situated

Comment: Calling `Wait()` on a task is a big no-no in many scenarios; if the scenario here has a sync-context (and I suspect it does), it is entirely possible that you will deadlock by doing that. Basically: **don't do that** (or access `.Result`); can you not simply `await` here?

Comment: @Sebastian Schumann i try to implemented but dont success. I implemented interface public interface IAsyncInitialization
{
    Task Initialization { get; }
}---------------------------------public PrometPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IPrometDanService servicePrometDan,IEventAggregator eventAggregator, Prism.Services.IPageDialogService pageDialogService, IAsyncInitialization asc) : base(navigationService)//,IEventAggregator ea
        {...Initialization = MyMethodAsync();}public Task Initialization { get; private set; }

Comment: Sorry - but this code is unreadable. Please post it so something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/ or whatever. What are your problems? You only told me that you don't have any success but I don't see what problem do you have.

Comment: Short,I have 4 mehtod which from api get data from database.Method type are private async Task,and in construktor i go NameOfMethod.Wait();  For me ideal solution and i want to get first method to wait for data.and rest 3 to work paralel in the background and dont wait their result.How to do that?

Comment: For the rest 3 method, you can put it in the Android background service. it will not affect the First method.

Comment: This is code for iOS,Android and UWP.I dont work only for one platform.And i want to learn...I try to  async Task subbstitution with async void but app dont work then.

Answer (score -2):

## Answer

The best way to handle your scenario is to use `async void`.

I recommend first reading the `Explanation` section below to fully understand the best practices around `async void`.

```cs
public MyConstructor()
{
    ExecuteAsyncMethods();
}

async void ExecuteAsyncMethods()
{ 
    try
    {
        await OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, DatumVrednost);
        await OnLoadPrometNedelja(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDatNedelja);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
```

### Explanation

Many C# devs are taught "Never use `async void`", but this is one of the few use-cases for it.

Yes `async void` can be dangerous and here's why:

- Cannot `await` an `async avoid` method
- Can lead to race conditions
- Difficult to catch an `Exception` thrown by `async void` methods

  - E.g. the following `try/catch` block will not catch the `Exception` thrown here:

```cs
public MyConstructor()
{
    try
    {
        //Cannot await `async void`
        AsyncVoidMethodWithException();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Will never catch the `Exception` thrown in  `AsyncVoidMethodWithException` because `AsyncVoidMethodWithException` cannot be awaited
    }

    //code here will be executing by the time `AsyncVoidMethodWithException` throws the exception
}

async void AsyncVoidMethodWithException()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    throw new Exception();
}
```

That being said, as long as we wrap the contents of our entire `async void` in a `try/catch` block, we will be able to catch the exception, like so:

```cs
public MyConstructor()
{
    AsyncVoidMethodWithException();
}

async void AsyncVoidMethodWithException()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Exception will be caught and successfully handled 
    }
}
```

## SafeFireAndForget

I created a library to help with this and its additional benefit is that it avoids writing `async void` code that could be potentially misused by future devs.

It's open source and also available on NuGet:

- [Source Code](https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices.git)
- [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/)

#### SafeFireAndForget

`SafeFireAndForget` allows us to safely execute a `Task` whilst not blocking the calling thread and without waiting for it to finish before moving to the next line of code.

Below is a simplified version of `SafeFireAndForget` that you can add to your project.

However, I recommend copy/pasting its [complete source code](https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/blob/master/Src/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/SafeFireAndForgetExtensions.cs) or adding its [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/) to your library to get a more robust implementation

```cs
public static async void SafeFireAndForget<TException>(this Task task, Action<TException> onException = null, bool continueOnCapturedContext = false) where TException : Exception
{
    try
    {
        await task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
    }
    catch (TException ex) when (onException != null)
    {
        onException(ex);
    }
}
```

#### Using SafeFireAndForget

To use `SafeFireAndForget`, append it to your method call like so:

```cs
OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, DatumVrednost).SafeFireAndForget();
OnLoadPrometNedelja(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDatNedelja).SafeFireAndForget();
```

To handle any `Exception` thrown by that `Task`, use `onException`. Here's an example that prints the `Exception` to the Debug Console:

```cs
OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, DatumVrednost).SafeFireAndForget(ex => Debug.WriteLine(ex));
OnLoadPrometNedelja(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDatNedelja).SafeFireAndForget(ex => Debug.WriteLine(ex));
```

Comment: I think that the simplified version of `SafeFireAndForget` will crash the application in case that `onException` is `null`. To male it truly safe you must include an unconditional `catch` in the block.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are correct, and that's one of my objectives with this library: to surface an `Exception` in the `Task`. If a `Task` is called without `await`, and an `Exception` is thrown inside that `Task`, the `Exception` will disappear forever. I've seen too many devs call a `Task` without `await`ing it and then wonder why their code got into an unexpected state.

Comment: In that case, if crashing the application is intentional, then I don't think that the name `HandleSafeFireAndForget` is appropriate for this method. I suggest that you make the `onException` argument mandatory, and add another method named for example `OnExceptionThrowUnhandled` that communicates clearly what is going to happen in case of an exception in the task!

Comment: To be clear, SafeFireAndForget doesn’t crash your code. Rather, non-handled exceptions in poorly written code crash the code. SafeFireAndForget ensures that all exceptions are rethrown by the compiler-generated IAsyncStateMachine.

Comment: Then in what aspect is "safe" the `SafeFireAndForget` method? And how am I supposed to "forget" something that can crash my application at any moment? It makes no sense to me. Besides that, if I really wanted my application to crash on any faulted task that I didn't `await`, I could simply configure the application with `<runtime><ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/></runtime>` in App.config, instead of chaining a misleadingly named method to all of my tasks.

Comment: A relevant quote from an old Stephen Cleary's answer: *Avoid async void. It has tricky semantics around error handling; I know some people call it "fire and forget" but I usually use the phrase "fire and crash".* [citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803012/fire-and-forget-with-async-vs-old-async-delegate/12804036#12804036)

Comment: And another one: *Regarding "fire and forget": I personally never use this phrase for async void methods. For one thing, the error handling semantics most certainly do not fit in with the phrase "fire and forget"; I half-jokingly refer to async void methods as "fire and crash".* [citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659603/async-void-asp-net-and-count-of-outstanding-operations/17660475#17660475)

Comment: I had to downvote as while `async void` will do the trick it is strictly recommended to use this only in exceptional situations (event handlers) exactly because that's not safe.